Leveraging Salesforce External Identity License for Custom Portals
I want to build a customized portal outside of salesforce with UI and functionalities that Salesforce Experience not able to provide. However, part of my portal still need to leveraging data stored in Salesforce, like create and access CRM Data.
I am currently exploring what technology can I use to do User Identity Management for the my portal. And I am reading about "External Identity License" (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_external_identity.htm&type=5)
It seems like fitting our needs, and provides the advantage of accessing Salesforce Objects(Standard and Custom).
I am wondering if any one has been using salesforce "External Identity License" for their custom implementation. What are get pros and cons for using Salesforce as User Identity Management Service. What is the price when having over 10,000+ user using this license. How much difference in terms of price comparing this License and other external licenses like (Community Plus License) this one saves.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. The pricing questions should go to your Salesforce account team - the publicly available prices tend to be discounted for larger volumes of users. Your other questions are very broad and are not a good fit for this forum.

will modify my question to be more specific
